# Eclipse IDE's Hello World Cheatsheet seems to have a mistake

Tags: java, eclipse

Just a warning: I'm completely new to Java and am trying to teach myself Android programming.

I installed the Eclipse IDE today and tried to walk through the first Java Hello World "cheat sheet," and it didn't work! I was really quite surprised.

When it asked me to select the checkbox to create the main() method, there wasn't anything on-screen that looked like a checkbox with "main()" or "method" next to it, so I guessed that maybe what they meant was the "Modifiers" radio button. So I left that checked for "public."

It didn't compile and I got red X's next to every folder in my Package Explorer.

Has anybody else had this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: With regard to those red X's: in the right bottom box, click the tab *Problems*. You'll see them all in detail there. Those ought to be self-explaining (or at least, Googleable). If in vain, just update your question to include them and we'll assist you in solving them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a class is there a section that asks:

> ```
> Which method stubs would you like to create?
> ```

check the box labeled

> ```
> public static void main(String[] args)
> ```

Edit: Also, it may be the case that you created an `Interface` instead of a `Class`, which may explain why you didn't see this option, if it actually wasn't there.

Answer (score 1):

I just went through it, and it is correct. You should have seen those instructions when looking at a dialog called "New Java Class", which is on the step "Create your HelloWorld class". There is a checkbox under "Which method stubs would you like to create?" labeled "public static void main(String[] args)". That's the one the cheat sheet is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

`public static void main(String[] args)`